# Java Hibernate populate transient property

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I have several entities that have transient properties that I would like to populate from the sql query. I have tried several things but have not found the correct combination yet.

here is an example entity

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
long id;
@Size(max=1000)
String image_url;

@Transient
boolean liked;

@Transient
long numLikes;

**getters and setters** for persistent properties

    public boolean isLiked() {
    return liked;
}

public void setLiked(boolean liked) {
    this.liked = liked;
}

public long getNumLikes() {
    return numLikes;
}

public void setNumLikes(long numLikes) {
    this.numLikes = numLikes;
}
```

I have tried using the @Basic anotation and setting it's fetch method to eager

```
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

on the getters but that didn't seem to do anything. I've seen it set to lazy as well.

Am I missing anything in here that would cause a column name not be mapped to one of these transient properties?

here is my impl code.

```
SQLQuery query = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("" +
            "SELECT * ,count(likes1.liked) as numLikes " +
            "FROM aboutme " +
            "left JOIN " +
            "(" +
            "   select liked, likedObject_id " +
            "   from likes " +
            "   where liked = 1" +
            ") as likes1 ON aboutme.id = likes1.likedObject_id " +
            "left join " +
            "(" +
            "   select likedObject_id, liked " +
            "   from likes " +
            "   where liked = 1 and profile_id = :id" +
            ") as likes2 on likes2.likedObject_id = aboutme.id " +
            "WHERE aboutme.profile_id = :id " +
            "group by aboutme.id");

    query.addEntity(AboutMe.class);
    query.setParameter("id",id);

    return query.list();
```

I've tried using the

```
  SQLQuery query = ..."Select count(value that returns properly) as {object.numLikes}..."


 query.addEntity("object",Object.class),
```

I get an error here that says it can't find the column name for property [property] for alias [alias]

What am I doing wrong?

Transient properties are probably not the way to go for what I am trying to do. what I need to figure out is how to map these derived columns to an object that I can return to the front end. how do I set up an object that hibernate can map these aliased columns to properties?

Comment: Transient is marked for fields/methods that should never take part in database persistence. They are not persistent. Why do you need to have these fields annotated like that anyway, what is the reason?

Comment: ok maybe transient properties aren't the route I need to go. I have a one to many relationship. for the likes part. maybe I should return two objects in the list and run it that way? is there a way to return a derived property that isn't part of the table entity? how have you done/seen this done?

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate will never populate your transient fields and what is most important transient fields are not even part of the java serialization process. What I would try if you really need this - is the `ResultTransformer.alliasToBean` which is "injecting" the values into the class with reflection.

```
setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Yourclass.class));
```

Just a quick idea, not sure whether it will work.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you go this route, the class doesn't even need to be an entity at all (which arguably the asker's class isn't, since it doesn't actually seem to map to a table)

Comment: This class does map to a table. but what I'm trying to figure out is how to make the table with extra derived fields map to an object that I can return to the front end.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. You can set the transient property though it's kind of a pain.

using the addScalar Method on the SQLQuery object you can set the transient properties. However if it is done this way you have to set ALL the properties in the object this way (Hibernate doesn't autofill any properties)

Also you will have to use the setResultTransformer Method also on the SQLQuery object. So to finish off my previous example I would have to add the following code in my impl.

```
 //  query.addEntity(AboutMe.class); <- this contradicts the setResultTransformer
 query.setParameter("id",id);

 query.addScalar("id",StandardBasicTypes.LONG);
 query.addScalar("image_url",StandardBasicTypes.LONG);
 query.addScalar("liked",StandardBasicTypes.LONG);
 query.addScalar("numLikes",StandardBasicTypes.LONG);

 query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Object.class));
```

where Object is the class that I am wanting to use that has all these properties declared.

Comment: I feel like you are trying to make your project very complicated here which is unnecessary. Maybe should take a look at your data model or see some examples how things can be done better. For me it seems you are trying to move away from what Hibernate is meant for.

Comment: ok. Let me perhaps rephrase the question how do I put derived data that isn't persisted in the same table into an object and return it. so far this is the only way I've seen. or stuffing into a pojo but that would be the same process.

Comment: @C-Rad I believe your question is well stated. I am looking to do the same thing and it has not been clear how to, if possible, do so.